# Codeigniter's URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I'm using the following `htaccess` script so that I can hide `index.php` from the URI.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I'm facing a major problem :(

I have a directory named `assets` beside my `index.php` file and it should be there. When I browse the directory by browser, then Codeigniter’s **not found** page displays. I can't browse the file `/assets/image.jpg` but it displays when I call it from an `<img>` tag

What can I do now?

Note that it is working in my local server (`localhost`) but not in the live server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

That'll pass any request that Apache wouldn't serve off to CodeIgniter. This way you're free to create directories all over without updating your rewrite rules, and you don't need to setup 404 handling in Apache (even inside your image/resource directories).

Credit goes to the Zend Framework authors that recommend this bit in their user guide. This version is slightly modified for CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the .htaccess file I use for my CI install:

If you have it in a subfolder you will need to edit RewriteBase.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You mean you haven't already moved the system folder outside of the public directory? What happens when you (or your admin) disables AllowOverride on accident? CI has the messy aborts on all of their files, but have you verified that your files are safe to be the point-of-entry for a user? It's easier just to move the system folder up to the parent and have a separate public directory.

Comment: Yes that's true and I moved my system folder on my production server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete solution which i am using and found working nicely:

Place this code snippet below in .htaccess file at your project root like http://localhost/myProject

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appDirName
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^appDirName.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And at your CI config file located at system\application\config\config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Put your installation directory here:
RewriteBase /
# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
# - index.php (DO NOT FORGET THIS!)
# - robots.txt
# - favicon.ico
# - Any file inside of the images/, js/, or css/ directories 
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|images|js|css)
# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I use this and it work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following into your .htaccess

```
# Change "welcome" to your default controller:
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, 
# if not send them to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```